# How to set an interface on an existing, but currently unknown, key/value pair?

Tags: typescript, interface

I have the following interface:

```js
interface Item {
    _id: string;
    name: string;
    amount: number;
    type: 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
    value: string;
}
```

Now I want to create a generic method for updating *one* of the values, which can be *any of the five*.

Simplified, the function looks like:

```js
patch(item: Item, key: any, value: any): Item {
    return {
        ...item,
        [key]: value
    };
}
```

---

- What to use for the `key`?
- What to use for the `value`?

Comment: `patch(item, 7, false); // no error `

Comment: @jcalz Ah you're right! `keyof` doesn't work at all. It just didn't give a compile error. I'll remove it from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code will allow the unfortunate calling of `patch` like

```
declare const item: Item;
patch(item, 7, false); // no error
```

despite the fact that `7` is not a valid property key of `Item`, and `false` is not a valid property value for that or any key of `Item`.

---

Let's examine your particular `Item` interface and see what [`keyof` and lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) do to it.

The `keyof` type operator takes an object type and returns the type of its keys.  If the object doesn't have an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types), that type should be the union of [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) corresponding to its known-valid keys:

```
type KeysOfItem = keyof Item
// type KeysOfItem = "_id" | "name" | "amount" | "type" | "value"
```

So you want the `key` parameter to be one of those.  Now, let's say you have a valid key like `"amount"`. Then you can look up the property type for that key like this:

```
type ItemAmount = Item["amount"];
// type ItemAmount = number
```

So for whatever the type `K` the `key` parameter is, you want the `value` parameter to be `Item[K]`.

---

So a first shot at your function type could be something like this:

```
function patch(item: Item, key: keyof Item, value: Item[keyof Item]): Item {
    return {
        ...item,
        [key]: value
    };
}

declare const item: Item;
patch(item, 7, false); // error! 7 is not a key, false is not a value
```

That's better, but:

```
patch(item, "name", 14); // no error
```

The problem is that there is no correlation between the particular `key` you used and the `value` you passed.  Since `"name"` is *some* key, and `number` is *some* acceptable value (for `"amount"`), then it doesn't error.

The way to fix this is to make `key` a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) type `K` that can be *more specific than* (or "extend") `keyof Item` and then constrain `value` to type `Item[K]`:

```
function patch<K extends keyof Item>(item: Item, key: K, value: Item[K]): Item {
    return {
        ...item,
        [key]: value
    };
}

declare const item: Item;
patch(item, 7, false); // error! 7 is not a key, false is not a value
patch(item, "name", 14); // error! 14 is not a string
patch(item, "name", "okay"); // works
patch(item, "amount", 14); // okay
```

So that is what I'd suggest. Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Definately helpfull. I appreciate the extra context and links too.

Answer (score 2):

Since the value type **depends** on the key passed, you should use a generic type parameter.

- We can define Key as extending keyof Item (this means Key is assignable to the type keyof Item)
- Then use Key to index the item type for the value (Item[Key]).

Result:

```
function patch<Key extends keyof Item>(item: Item, key: Key, value: Item[Key]): Item {
    return {
        ...item,
        [key]: value
    };
}
```

You could go one step of abstraction further. It's not important that this function is aware of the type of item:

```
function patch<TItem, TKey extends keyof TItem>(item: TItem, key: Key, value: TItem[Key]): TItem {
    return {
        ...item,
        [key]: value
    };
}
```

Now with any item you pass, you can patch a value

Comment: Very nice, just tested it, and now it only accepts known keys. Also thanks for the second one, Definitely comes in handy for my generic Store class. Great, thanks!

Comment: @JeffreyRoosendaal no worries! updated it with a non-item specific version too

Comment: I hope you don't mind I choose the other answer as the accepted one, even though you were first!